# String of text hidden?

Tags: java, swing, text

I have a string of text "Highscore: " and I want this to show up at the bottom of my JFrame. When I try to increase the y the text shows up to about 100 and then if I want to increase it anymore it disappears? I want it past 100 though...

**Here is my code:**

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;




public class Game {


public static void main(String[] args) {

     final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tennis Game");
     frame.setSize(300,400);
     frame.setResizable(false);
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     //Graphics add
     Menu graphics = new Menu();

     frame.add(graphics);
     graphics.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 100);

     frame.setLayout(null);

     //Buttons
     //Play button
     final JButton b = new JButton("Play");

     b.setFocusPainted(false);
     b.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20));
     b.setBounds(110,100,80,40);
     b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

     b.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter(){

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
             b.setForeground(Color.RED);
             b.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
         }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
             b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
         }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){


        }

     });

     //Exit button
     final JButton b2 = new JButton("Exit");

     b2.setFocusPainted(false);
     b2.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20));
     b2.setBounds(110, 180, 80, 40);
     b2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

     b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);

        }



     });

     b2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter(){

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
             b2.setForeground(Color.RED);
             b2.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
         }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
             b2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
         }

     });

     //Help Button
     final JButton b3 = new JButton("Help");

     b3.setFocusPainted(false);
     b3.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20));
     b3.setBounds(110, 140, 80, 40);
     b3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

     b3.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter(){

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
             b3.setForeground(Color.RED);
             b3.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
         }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
             b3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
         }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){


        }

     });


     frame.add(b);
     frame.add(b2);
     frame.add(b3);


 }
 }
```

**Also:**

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;



public class Menu extends JPanel {

int highscore = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30)); 
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("TENNIS GAME", 40, 60);

    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18)); 
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("Made by Jared Butterfield", 36, 82);

    //TEXT HERE
    //TEXT HERE
    //TEXT HERE
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18)); 
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("Highscore: "+ highscore, 0, 150);


}


}
```

I tried to add comments where the highscore text was for help.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 2):

> I have a string of text "Highscore: " and I want this to show up at the bottom of my JFrame.

Create a JLabel and then add the label to the frame using:

```
frame.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

This assumes you are using the default `BorderLayout` for the frame, which is always a good idea.

All your other custom painting code should be replaced by JLabels as well. Again you add the labels to a panel using an appropriate layout managers. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and demo code to get you started.

Comment: @CoderofJava, you're welcome. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the fact that you are using `null` layouts, then move onto the fact that you purposefully set the bounds of the `Menu` component to `graphics.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 100);` (100px high), but then paint the text at the y position of `150`, `g.drawString("Highscore: " + highscore, 0, 150);` and then wonder why it doesn't display?

1. Don't use `null` layouts, you are just asking for trouble.  Make use of appropriate layout managers
2. Use `JLabel` to render text, it's what it does and it does it well

See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Is there a layout that will look like the way I have my buttons set up now?